# Is this sentence with repeated use of "what" correct?

Tags: what

I'm a french speaker and I have a question about the use of "what" at the beginning of a sentence. Could you please tell me if the following sentences are correct?

1. What experiences, what feelings, what problems does it come from?
2. What feelings? What energy?

The context is about an experience in painting.

I don't think I have to use "which" instead of "what", but I'm not sure.

Comment: They sound fine to me (native British speaker), and better than "which".

Comment: Sounds like parts of a speech, a strong reaction...

Comment: You are not a 'french speaker'. You are a **French** speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *which* is a relative pronoun used (in many cases) to distinguish one among many: "Which jacket do you prefer?"

The word *what* is a more generalized term that can refer to anything: "What do you want to do today?"

Therefore, "What experiences, what feelings, what problems does it come from?" is correct because it leaves open for respondents to supply **any** experiences, feelings, or problems they see fit. To use the word *which* in your examples would be unnaturally limiting.

Comment: Unless of course somebody was holding up a number of charts, each of which contained a list of words or phrases that described experiences, feelings, and problems. Context would then make *which* more appropriate in the otherwise identical sentence. However, since the particular context is already given in the question, that's not the case.